# Able to deserialize string type but not object type

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

I am using C# with JSON.NET. Below are the two types.

```
   JSON object -  var user = { "name": "test", "title": "mytitle"};
   JSON String -  var user1 = "{ \"name\": \"test\", \"title\": \"mytitle\" }";
```

Using Newtonsoft.Json to deserialize the JSON object. C# Code in which I am handling JSON.

```
      public class sampledata
      {
        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string name { get; set; }

         [JsonProperty("title")]
        public string title { get; set; }
      }
     public void SampleEvent(string param)
        {

            sampledata s = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<sampledata>(param);
         }
```

**When I got JSON String in param the deserialization is fine.** But when I got JSON object in param - First error I am getting is

> > "Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'UCRS.MainWindow+sampledata' because the type requires a JSON object
> >     (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
>
> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g.
>   {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a
>   type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList)
>   like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array.
>   JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to
>   deserialize from a JSON array.
>
> Path '', line 1, position 1.

So I changed the code as :

```
      List<sampledata> s = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<sampledata>>(param);
```

Then I am facing different issue

> " Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: o. Path '',
>   line 1, position 1."

When some event is raised in web page I am handling that event in c# using webbrowser objectforscripting. I always get the JSON object as param. How to deserialize JSON object in C#? Please help

Comment: post the exact json string which throwing this error and not a mock up

Comment: How do you call the method with the object? object.ToString() will not work, because the object is an anonymous type and will not tostring to a JSON string

Comment: @Rahul - it is the same example throwing error. { "name": "test", "title": "mytitle"} This is the JSON object when trying to deserialize throwing error.

Comment: @SwethaBindu - you cannot deserialize an object (as in "read binary/string representation into an in-memory object") - it already is, just not of the type you would like.

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty simple..working for both

```
string jsonObject = @"{""name"":""test"",""title"":""mytitle""}";
var jsonString = "{ \"name\": \"test\", \"title\": \"mytitle\" }";

var values1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(jsonObject);
var values2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(jsonString);
```

This is also working

```
var values3 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<sampledata>(jsonObject);
```

I created JObject

```
           JObject jObject = new JObject
           {
               {"name", "test" },
               {"title", "mytitle" }
           };
           string jObjectStr = jObject.ToString();
var values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<sampledata>(jObjectStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

The updated line of code:

```
List<sampledata> s = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<sampledata>>(param);
```

is perfectly fine.

The problem here is that the deserializer is expecting an array when you are trying to deserialize to a list.

Try making it an array. Add this line of code to the param string:

```
param ="["+param+"]";//make it an array before deserialization
```

Complete code:

```
public class sampledata
  {
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string name { get; set; }

     [JsonProperty("title")]
    public string title { get; set; }
  }
 public void SampleEvent(string param)
    {
        param ="["+param+"]";//make it an array before deserialization
        List<sampledata> s = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<sampledata>>(param);
     }
```